# Symfony 4 - FullCalendar filtering with Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony

On my symfony 4 project, I use FullCalendar to display absences.
An absence has a type of absence. By default I display all absences.
But I would like to display a kind of form that would display as a checkbox all types of possible absences. And each time we check / uncheck one, the calendar is updated thanks to an Ajax request.

So, how should I display my checkboxes? With a formBuilder that would allow me with a {{form_row (form.types)}} to display all led checkboxes?

In my Javascript, I declare my calendar like this :

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
           //...
```

So there should be an onChange () function on my row of checkboxes to capture each change, to then call the Ajax function that manages my absences, and send it as a filter checked checkboxes

Comment: Maybe instead of making an ajax request each time checkbox change you can load all absence and filter by using "eventRender" event ?

Comment: Oh yes, I see what you mean! You're right it's better! But how can I do that in my eventRender?

Comment: You can do something like that (inside eventRender): ```let absenceCategory = [];
$("input:checkbox:checked").each(function () {
    absenceCategory.push($(this).data('equipmentId'));
});
return $.inArray(event.absenceCategory, absenceCategory) >= 0;```

Comment: Ok if I understand correctly you declare the table that will contain the events. Then for each checkbox checked, you retrieve the events that have the type corresponding to the checkbox, and you put them in the table and you return the table is that?

But I do not understand this line:
absenceCategory.push ($ (this) .data ( 'equipmentId')); });

What is 'equipmentId'?
Can not make a condition by collecting each event and analyzing their type, and if they have the right type, put them in the table?

Comment: Sorry that's a mistake for 'equipmentId' (this is a copy/paste from my code). The for each retrieve all id of type of absence we want (from your checkbox) and at the end we check inside your event if the category is in the array(list of category we want to show), if eventRender return true the event will be show.